# Google pickers fonts option isn't working

Tags: google-picker

Previously I was using google picker to select available google fonts. but recently it started throwing 403 error.

`var oView = new google.picker.View('fonts'); picker.hideTitleBar() .addView(oView) .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)`

It was working previously but recently it started showing 403 error.